# PHP get_meta_tags parameter use_include_path

Tags: php

I can't seem to get the get_meta_tags `use_include_path` parameter to work on my local file. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing a piece of code?

Here is my full code:

```
  $file = get_meta_tags('file:///C:/wamp/www/b.htm', true);
  
  echo $file['author'];
  echo $file['keywords'];
  echo $file['description'];
```

Comment: You are specifying a full path. I imagine that `use_include_path` will fail in that constellation. Try just `b.htm`

Comment: I get nothing what exactly is the use_include_path supposed to do should it open the file in a new window?

Comment: new window? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

PHP manual page for [get_meta_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) says that

> Setting `use_include_path` to `TRUE` will result in PHP trying to open the file along the standard include path as per the `include_path` directive. This is used for local files, not URLs.

So to get the `include_path` working you should reference the file without the url syntax and make sure that the file can be found along the path set in `include_path`.

Comment: @glen what are you trying to do with it in the first place?

Comment: @Pekka, it seems that the use_include_path parameter really dosn't do anything because I can get the same results without it.

Comment: As the documentation says, `use_include_path` is only used when accessing a local file.

Comment: @glen *what are you trying to do with it in the first place?*